# Horizontal Line appearing in HTML Email message format - Outlook office 365

Tags: html, css, outlook, media-queries

I am trying to send an email from outlook (office 365) as HTML format. There is a thin line appearing in a large screen monitor(27 inch or more) or with a zoom level 175%. The below code doesn't show any horizontal line with 100% zoom in office 365 outlook, but if I increase the zoom (Click tab , Format Text --> Zoom) to (170%-200%), a horizontal line appears randomly below some part of header ex; Information -2 header, title header (image attached). 
[image: Horizontal line Image 1]
[image: Horizontal line Image 2]

Here is my html that I am inserting in outlook mail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Request Submitted</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }
        /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
        
        body {
            width: 100% !important;
            /*line-height: 100%;*/
        }
        
        .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }
        /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        
        body {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }
        /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */
        /* Reset Styles */
        
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass * {
            line-height: 100%;
        }
        
        body,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        div,
        table,
        u,
        td,
        p {
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        body {
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "Arial";
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 10px 0px;
        }
        
        h2,
        .h2 {
            display: block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: rgb(195, 203, 211);
            color: rgb(52, 73, 94);
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        h4 {
            margin-left: 9px;
        }
        
        div.statusLabel {
            display: block;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(195, 203, 211);
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        
        div.statusLabel.partialStatus {
            height: 36px;
        }
        
        div.statusLabel p {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        
        div.statusLabel span {
            display: none;
        }
        
        div.statusLabel.partialStatus span {
            display: inline;
        }
        
        div.statusTile {
            display: block;
            width: 98px;
            height: 98px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(195, 203, 211);
            border: 1px solid rgb(183, 192, 202);
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        
        div.statusTile.leftTile {
            margin-left: 0px !important;
        }
        
        div.statusTile p {
            position: relative;
            top: 36px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        div.statusTile span {
            display: none;
        }
        
        div.statusTile.twoLine span {
            display: block;
        }
        
        div.statusTile.twoLine p {
            top: 24px;
        }
        /*Colors*/
        
        .submitted {
            background-color: #0078D7 !important;
        }
        
        .approved {
            background-color: #107C10 !important;
        }
        
        .reserved {
            background-color: #FFB900 !important;
        }
   
        
        .noRibbon {
            border: 0 !important;
        }
        
    
        
        table table table {
            margin-top: -10px !important;
        }
        
   
        

    </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family: " Segoe UI ", open-sans, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-weight:lighter;">
    <table id="tblMain" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p style="font-size:16px;margin:0px"><b><i>Email Heading.</i></b> </p>
                                    <h1>This is a Test Email.</h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="28%" valign="top" style="padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                                    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding-top:10px;">
                                                                <td style="padding:10;background-color:#0078D7;">
                                                                    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Title - 1</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding:10;background-color:rgb(195,203,211);">
                                                                    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Title - 2</p>

                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding:10;background-color:rgb(195,203,211);">
                                                                    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Title - 3</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding:10;background-color:rgb(195,203,211);">
                                                                    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Title - 4</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding:10;background-color:rgb(195,203,211);">
                                                                    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Title - 5</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="72%" valign="top" style="padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                                        <!--Intro Text-->
                                                        <p style="line-height:20px;">Hello User,
                                                        </p>
                                                        <br /> Please ignore this email.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background-color:rgb(195,203,211);color:rgb(52,73,94);font-size:15px;padding:10px;"> <b style="color:rgb(52,73,94);">
Information - 1</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50%"><b>Header 1</b>: <span></span> </td>
                                                <td width="50%"><b>Header 2</b>: <span></span> </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50%"><b>Header 3</b>: <span></span> </td>
                                                <td width="50%"><b>Header 4</b>: <span></span> </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding:5px 10px;background-color:rgb(195,203,211);"> <b style="color:rgb(52,73,94);font-size:16px;">Information - 2</b> </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

> I have modified the td padding, the line disappears for td padding 10px, but that is not consistent. Can you please help me how can I remove the horizontal line for zoom level 180%? This issue can be seen with a monitor 27 inch or more.

Thank you.